# SQL Server Designer table re-creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Can I change the script the SSMS does when you use designer to alter your table which causes table re-creation?

I know the 'Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation' option but I want it to leave unchecked.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: For certain operations, SSMS will do a simple ALTER, but for others it does a table rebuild. Example, reordering columns.

Comment: Is there a way to change the script that performs table re-creation?

Comment: You can always copy the script and post in SSMS to run manually

Comment: What I want is to literally change the generated changed script on the said scenario based on my script, as I need those scripts for some triggers, sp etc. Well, I think it may be impossible as SSMS programmed that way. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this box to generate the script. From there, you can modify if you like.

[image]

Comment: What I want is to literally change the generated changed script on the said scenario based on my script, as I need those scripts for some triggers, sp etc. Well, I think it may be impossible as SSMS programmed that way. Thanks btw.